# Executing document.querySelectorAll do not seem to work from puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm using the following snippet to get some elements from a web page

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs/promises')

async function start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768});
    await page.goto("http://localhost:8080/")
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000)
    await page.screenshot({ path: "isc-loc-1.png", fullPage: true})

    const reportElts = await page.evaluate( ()=> {
        return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("span.css-13whmom")).map(x => x.innerText)
    })

    console.log("Number of Rows in Report: ",reportElts.length)

    await browser.close()
}

start()
```

It terminates successfully but I'm getting an empty Array.

The issue is that if I use Chrome developer tools accessing the same server and using the following statement in the console

```
var myV=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("span.css-13whmom")).map(x => x.innerText)
```

I'm actually getting the reality which is an array of 245 elements. I thought it might have been due to the page not loaded but I can see the screenshot generated by the script.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong ? Or are they known limitation/bug from Puppeteer that might explain this.

P.S I tested this [simple tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgyszZhAZOI) & it works fine on my setup.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Code looks fine. I don't have access to the site so it's pretty hard to say what the problem could be. Can you share a [mcve]? Often, when you can select it in the dev tools but not in Pupp, it's because the elements are in an iframe. Check if `console.log(await page.$("iframe"))` isn't null. Since it's localhost, though, I assume this is your site, so you can probably tell what's in it easily.

Comment: @ggorlen, thx you so much this was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot @ggoren, I now rewrote this simple snippet like that. Might be helpful for some other newbies on puppeteer like me. In my case there was a second frame and it was the one containing the elements I was trying to select.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8080');
  await dumpFrameTree(page.mainFrame(), '');
  await browser.close();

  async function dumpFrameTree(frame, indent) {
    console.log(indent + frame.url());
    const reportElts = await frame.evaluate( ()=> {
      return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("span.css-13whmom")).map(x => x.innerText)
    })
    console.log("Number of Rows in Report: ",reportElts.length)
    for (const child of frame.childFrames()) {
      await dumpFrameTree(child, indent + '  ');
    }
  }


})();
```